# How can I aggregate a list or series whose values are stored as a 1:1 relationship?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
            Col1            Col2

row1        A1               A2

row2        A2               A3

row3        A2               A4

row4        A3               A5

row5        B1               B2

row6        B2               A3
```

I need to identify the values of Col1 which never appear as a value of Col2 (we'll call these MasterValues) and generate a list or comma delimited string of all values which are related to the MasterValue. In this example A1 and B1 would be MasterValues.

Expected Output:

```
                Col1            Col2

row1            A1              A2,A3,A4,A5

row2            B1              B2,A3
```

Note that there are thousands of rows, and some values (such as A3 in this example) are used for more than one MasterValue. Also important to note is that a lot of values occur more than once in Col1 (such as A2 in this example,) including some MasterValues.

The first step I figured would be to group the DF by Col1. Then, I figured I'd loop and append Col2 appropriately. I've tried a lot of variations and this is the closest I've gotten:

```
DF = pandas.read_sql(command, connection)
DF2 = DF
DF = DF.groupby('col1', as_index=False).agg({col2: lambda x: ','.join(x)}))

for xrow in DF.itertuples():
    for yrow in DF2.itertuples():
        if yrow[1] in xrow[2]:
            DF.at[xrow[0], 'col2'] = DF.at[xrow[0], 'col2'] + ',' + yrow[2]
```

However this still isn't right. I still end up with some values in Col1 which aren't MasterValues. I've searched and searched and thought and thought to no avail. Can anyone help me wrap my head around the logic needed to complete this?

Comment: Why is 'A5' not in the list for A1?

Comment: how do you define *related to the Master Value*? like a single connected Graph?

Comment: @Scott, A5 should have been there. I edited the question to reflect that, thanks

Comment: @Yuca, related meaning all values that are related to another value which is related to the MasterValue. Essentially, if any value ever occurs in col2, it should not have a record in col1. I need col1 to only contain values which never occur in col2

Comment: *related means all values that are related* that's not informative at all! from what I can grasp you want a single directed graph, network approaches will do just fine, check Scott's answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would like you to use networkx?

```
import networkx
import pandas as pd

d = {'Col1': {'row1': 'A1',
  'row2': 'A2',
  'row3': 'A2',
  'row4': 'A3',
  'row5': 'B1',
  'row6': 'B2'},
 'Col2': {'row1': 'A2',
  'row2': 'A3',
  'row3': 'A4',
  'row4': 'A5',
  'row5': 'B2',
  'row6': 'A3'}}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)


G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'Col1', 'Col2', create_using=nx.DiGraph())

master = [n for n in G.nodes if nx.ancestors(G, n)==set()]
descendants = [list(nx.descendants(G,m)) for m in master]

pd.DataFrame({'col1':master,'col2':descendants})
```

Output:

```
  col1              col2
0   A1  [A3, A5, A4, A2]
1   B1      [A5, A3, B2]
```